# Split / explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with polars

Tags: pandas, python-polars

I am working with a 3.2Gb csv and have loaded this into a polars dataframe for processing. One of the columns contains python dictionaries in string format like this (see "_source"):

```
shape: (5, 9)
┌─────────────┬───────┬─────────────┬──────────┬───┬─────────────┬───────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ _index      ┆ _type ┆ _id         ┆ _version ┆ … ┆ _primary_te ┆ found ┆ _source    ┆ _ignored   │
│ ---         ┆ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---      ┆   ┆ rm          ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ str         ┆ str   ┆ str         ┆ i64      ┆   ┆ ---         ┆ bool  ┆ str        ┆ str        │
│             ┆       ┆             ┆          ┆   ┆ i64         ┆       ┆            ┆            │
╞═════════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪══════════╪═══╪═════════════╪═══════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ index-strin ┆ _doc  ┆ e5EL4GUC2TF ┆ 8        ┆ … ┆ 11          ┆ true  ┆ {'update_d ┆ null       │
│ g-goes-here ┆       ┆ BdJZvL4eiTk ┆          ┆   ┆             ┆       ┆ t': '2023- ┆            │
│ -something  ┆       ┆             ┆          ┆   ┆             ┆       ┆ 10-26T07:5 ┆            │
│             ┆       ┆             ┆          ┆   ┆             ┆       ┆ 4:…        ┆            │
```

The dictionaries in the column have exactly the same set of keys and all the values have the same format between rows. I'd like to expand the contents of this column out so that there is a new column for each of the keys in the dictionary. I've checked the documentation and asked ChatGPT but can't find any answers.

In pandas, I've done this on a smaller dataset with something like:

```
df['_source'] = df['source'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
pd.concat([df.drop(['_source'], axis=1), df['_source'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

But this takes forever in pandas so I want to use polars. duckdb is another option but I feel like sql would get very complicated quickly. Open to suggestions though.

For the first step of converting the string to a dict, I tried this in polars:

```
df = pl.read_csv(csv_file)
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("_source").apply(ast.literal_eval))
```

But I get this error:

```
ComputeError: ComputeError: got mixed dtypes while constructing List Series
```

From the error it seems that it can't handle what is returned by ast.literal_eval. As I said above, the keys are all the same and the values have the same format so I'm not sure why it is throwing this error. Is there any other way to do this I might be missing? Why can pandas handle this command but polars cannot?

Also not sure what the command would be to convert the dict into new columns.

**Update**
I realised it would be possible to get the data in the form of a ndjson file with properly formatted json in the `_source` column. Trying `read_json` crashed my server and using `scan_ndjson` resulted in the following Compute error:
`ComputeError: expected list/array in json value, got str`

I'm sure I could get to the bottom of this but instead of spending more time on it I've gone back to loading the csv into an eager dataframe and then just using string filtering to extract the data I need like so:
`deleted = df.filter(pl.col('_source').str.contains("'state': 'deleted'"))`

Comment: Can you provide an actual row of data from the csv file?

Comment: it is sensitive info so no, unfortunately. What specifically are you interested to see? The "_source" column is a very large dict with lots of keys and values of different types. It is not valid json as has single quotation marks.

Comment: Basically to see the actual structure/shape/types. The values themselves aren't important and could be replaced with dummies/placeholders. The main issue here is that Polars columns are "typed" and all values in the column must be of the same type. So you will likely have to split up `source` into separate columns. Perhaps you can `json.dumps()` the result of `ast.literal_eval()` to keep it as a string which would then allow you to use the answer already shown.

Comment: I've decided to give up on converting all the columns and just filter using `str.contains()` from the string representation

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for `.str.json_decode`, e.g.:

```py
In [36]: df = pl.DataFrame({'_source': ['{"update_time": "2023-01-01", "value": 3}']*2})

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ _source                           │
│ ---                               │
│ str                               │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ {"update_time": "2023-01-01", "v… │
│ {"update_time": "2023-01-01", "v… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘

In [38]: df.select(pl.col('_source').str.json_decode()).unnest('_source')
Out[38]:
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────┬───────┐
│ update_time ┆ value │
│ ---         ┆ ---   │
│ str         ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-01  ┆ 3     │
│ 2023-01-01  ┆ 3     │
└─────────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: this gives them multiple columns - `'_source'` was exploded into `'update_time'` and `'value'`

Comment: it is not valid json unfortunately so this doesn't work. Any ideas for converting to valid json? Have tried `df = df.with_columns(pl.col('_source').apply(json.dumps))` and it fails - and `df = df.with_columns(pl.col('_source').str.replace("'",'"').str.json_decode())` doesn't seem to work either as there is still an error `ComputeError: error inferring JSON: Syntax at character 0`

Comment: @ashtonjesse You would need to try dump the result of literal_eval e.g. `.apply(lambda x: json.dumps(ast.literal_eval(x))))`

Comment: @ashtonjesse could you give an example of a single row please?

Comment: I would share the structure but it is very complicated with lots of fields and values of string, int, dict and array types. My hunch is that there is a value that it can't parse so not convinced sharing this massive and complicated structure with you would help. Also see update above - I have a workable solution without having to unnest `_source`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about joining the strings and use literal_eval to do them all at once as a list? Maybe like this:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd
dummydata=['{"update_d":"xxxxx"}','{"update_d":"xxxxx22"}']
df=pd.DataFrame(dummydata)
tmpdata="[" + ','.join(df[0].__array__()) +']'
df.loc[:,0] = ast.literal_eval(tmpdata)
```